# Retornar objeto entre telas - c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho uma dúvida sobre retornar um objeto de uma tela B para uma tela A, por exemplo.

Eu utilizo a forma abaixo, ocultando o `ShowDialog` da classe base, fazendo o "novo ShowDialog" retornar o que preciso. Segue exemplo de código da classe da tela que retornará o objeto:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //trato meu objeto
        Close();
    }

    public new tipo_meu_objeto ShowDialog()
    {
        base.ShowDialog();
        return meu_objeto;
    }
```

Sei também, por meio de outras perguntas já feitas aqui, que existem outras formas, como por exemplo utilizar a instância da tela criada e acessando a variável por meio dela.

Minha pergunta é: O que exemplifiquei é considerado uma boa maneira de resolver isso? Caso não, qual seria a melhor forma de tratar esse caso?

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

A melhor maneira de resolver o seu problema seria acrescentar uma nova propriedade na sua classe que é chamada, e dependendo do `DialogResult` informado, haja ou não conteudo. Exemplo:

```
public class JanelaDialogo : Window
{
    public object Resultado { get; private set; }

    private void OnClick_Sucesso(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // este será o valor de retorno do método ShowDialog()
        DialogResult = true;

        Resultado = "Sucesso";

        Close();
    }    
}
```

Utilização:

```
private void OnDialogo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var win = new JanelaDialogo();

    if (win.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var resultado = win.Resultado;
    }
}
```